# C - Swap first and last element in doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, swap, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to swap the first and last elements of a doubly linked list. So far i have the following code, where i create a list and add some numbers to it. But the output is the same list both times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node2 {
    int number;
    struct node2 *next, *prev;
};

void addNodeDouble(struct node2 **head, struct node2 **tail, int num, int thesi) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        struct node2 * current;
        current = (struct node2 *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct node2));
        current->number = num;
        current->prev = NULL;
        current->next = NULL;
        *head = current;
        *tail = current;
    } else {
        if (thesi == 1) {
            struct node2 *current, *temp;
            current = (struct node2 *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct node2));
            current->number = num;
            temp = *head;
            while (temp->next != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;

            temp->next = current;
            current->prev = *tail;
            current->next = NULL;
            (*tail)->next = current;
            *tail = current;
        } else  {
            struct node2 *current;
            current = (struct node2 *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct node2));
            current->number = num;
            current->next = *head;
            (*head)->prev = current;
            *head = current;
        }
    }
}

void ReversedisplayList(struct node2 **head, struct node2 **tail) {
    struct node2 *current;
    if (*head == NULL)
        printf("I lista einai adeia!\n");
    else {
        current = *tail;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", current->number);
            current = current->prev;
        }
    }
}

void swapElements2(struct node2 **head, struct node2 **tail) {
    struct node2 *current, *temp;

    temp = (*tail)->prev;
    current = *tail;

    temp->next = *head;
    current->next = (*head)->next;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
    *head = current;
}

int main() {
    struct node2 *head, *tail;
    head = tail = NULL;

    addNodeDouble(&head, &tail, 4, 1);
    addNodeDouble(&head, &tail, 8, 1);
    addNodeDouble(&head, &tail, 3, 0);
    addNodeDouble(&head, &tail, 1, 1);
    addNodeDouble(&head, &tail, 7, 0);

    printf("\n\nDoubly linked list (reversed): ");
    ReversedisplayList(&head, &tail);

    swapElements2(&head, &tail);
    printf("\nChanged list: ");
    ReversedisplayList(&head, &tail);
}
```

I get:

```
Doubly linked list (reversed): 1 8 4 3 7 
Changed list: 1 8 4 3 7
```

But I want:

```
Changed list: 7 8 4 3 1
```

Comment: You may want to consider swapping the data of the nodes instead of the nodes themselves. That would make things much easier for you in this case.

Comment: @Hypino No, i actually want to swap the nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the first and head and tail elements you have to walk through the following procedure.
First we have to get the previous node of tail and next node of head in some temporary variable and exchange head and tail's next and prev pointers.

```
void swapElements2(struct node2 **head, struct node2 **tail) {
    struct node2 *ttail, *thead;

    ttail = (*tail) -> prev;
    thead = (*head) -> next;

    (*head) -> next = NULL;
    (*tail) -> prev = NULL;

    (*head) -> prev = ttail;
    (*tail) -> next = thead;

    ttail -> next = (*head);
    thead -> prev = (*tail);

    (*tail)  = ttail -> next;
    (*head)  = thead -> next;
}
```

Comment: Indentation is not correct, and there should always be a short explanation, not just a code dump.

Comment: Thanks, i have added the explanation now.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, this makes it more readable and easier to follow.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what do u mean

Comment: @jafarbtech Thank you kind sir. This solved my problem. I appreciate your help and thanks for the explanation you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to alter `(*head) -> prev` and `(*tail) -> prev`.

```
(*head)->prev = temp;
(*tail)->prev = NULL;
```

Comment: Hmm, add these commands at the end of the swapElements2 function? Because if i do that, i get "Changed list: 1"([here](http://ideone.com/YouUbd))